# How do I find out how far the scrollbar is being scrolled?

Tags: javascript, scrollbar, scrollpane

I am trying to implement a scrollbar program that acts as a controller of denso robot arm. The denso robot arm would move accordingly to the positions of the scrollbars. How do I find out how far the scrollbar is being scrolled manually? Like the X and Y positions. I need the X and Y positions of the scrollbar to send the data to the robot arm. I have came across this website http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow , there was a tutorial on how to do it, but it can only calculate the browser's scrollbar position.

I'm trying to get the positions of these scrollbars.

[image: pic]
help please! I am still very new to javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pageXOffset`, `pageYOffset` (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_pagexoffset.asp)

> The pageXOffset and pageYOffset properties returns the pixels the
>   current document has been scrolled from the upper left corner of the
>   window, horizontally and vertically.

```js
window.onscroll=function(){
console.log(window.pageXOffset,window.pageYOffset);};
```

```html
<div style="height:3000px;width:3000px"></div>
```

For getting the position of the scrollbar of a generic object use `scrollLeft` and `scrollTop`

```js
scrollPane = document.getElementById("scrollpane");

scrollPane.onscroll=function(){
console.log(scrollPane.scrollLeft,scrollPane.scrollTop );};
```

```html
<div id="scrollpane" style="width:300px;height:60px;overflow:scroll;"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/sISz0.png"/></div>
```

Comment: How do I apply it to the scrollbars of the scrollpane on the browser? I don't want it to calculate the browser's scrollbar position.